# Align text to the same line as list item

Tags: html, css

This is my code:

```
* {
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
}

a {text-decoration:none;}

html,body {height: 100%;}
header {
    background:#CCEAF9;
background-image:url('http://wallpoper.com/images/00/45/05/47/green-background-2_00450547.jpg');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-attachment:fixed;
}
#featurenav {
    background:#000;
    color:#FFF;
    height:50px;
    transition:0.3s;
}
#featurenav span {
    display:inline-block;
    font-weight:bold;
    margin-right:1em;
    opacity:.5;
}
#featurenav span.active {
    opacity:1;
}
#featurenav.fixed {
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
    top:0;
    opacity: 0.9;
}
.fixed + #navPlaceholder {
    height:50px;
}
section {
    height:600px;
    background:#EEE;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #DDD 0%, #FFF 100%);
    padding:1em;
}
.full_height { height: 100%; }
.mid_height { height: 350px; }
.container {
    width: 780px;
    margin:0px auto;
}

#blackOverlay{background-color:#000;opacity:0.0;position:absolute;top:0;width:100%;height:100%;}

ul li{
  display: inline;
}
li {
    list-style-type: none;
}

#nav {padding-top: 30px;}
#nav ul {
    float: right;
}

#nav ul li a {
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
   opacity: .7;
    transition: opacity .3s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity .3s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .3s ease-out;
    -o-transition: opacity .3s ease-out;
font-family: proxima-nova, 'Proxima Nova', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
font-size: 13px;
font-weight: bold;
letter-spacing: 1px;
line-height: 35px;
padding-left: 10px;
padding-right: 10px;
text-transform: uppercase;
}

#nav ul li a:hover {
opacity: 1;
}

#nav ul li .active {
opacity: 1;
}

#nav img {
    float:left;
}

footer ul {
    float: right;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/h5am3/embedded/result/

How can I get the list on the right to sit on the same line as the text on the right? I am using `float: right;` but that doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest answer would be to add:

```
.container p{
    float:left;
}
```

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/h5am3/1/)

By default, the `p` you are using is block level 100% width, so takes up the width of the viewport forcing the list to be placed on the next line before being floated right.

Another alternative would be to set:

```
.container p {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

To ensure the `p` is subject to an 'inline' layouting

Comment: Sure- a width will have to be specified on the parent if displaying them if side by side is desired behaviour from the OP

Answer (score 0):

```
p {
    float: left;
}
```

try this